# When to use volatile vs synchronization in multithreading in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

When to use volatile keyword vs synchronization in multithreading?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214938/java-volatile-modifier-and-synchronized-blocks and a quick goggling will show a lot of information

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851133/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `volatile` to guarantee that each read access to a variable will see the latest value written to that variable. Use `synchronized` whenever you need values to be stable for multiple instructions. (Note that this does not necessarily mean multiple statements; the single statement:

```
var++; // NOT thread safe!
```

is *not* thread-safe even if `var` is declared `volatile`. You need to do this:

```
synchronized(LOCK_OBJECT){var++;}
```

See [here](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm051.shtml) for a nice summary of this issue.

Comment: `AtomicLong` handles the `var++` with a method and just a `volatile` field.  Can you edit your answer to provide a better example?

Comment: @Gray - Okay. My "better example" is that `var` is of type `float`.

Answer (score 10):

Volatile only ensures the read operation always gives the latest state from memory across threads. However, it does not ensure any write safety / ordering of operations, i.e. two threads can update the volatile variable in any random order. Also it **does not** ensure that multiple operations on the variable are atomic.

However a synchronized block ensures latest state and write safety. Also the access and update to variable is atomic inside a synchronized block.
The above, however is true, ***only if*** all the access / updates to the variable in question are using the same lock object so that at no time multiple threads gets access to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty broad question. The best answer I can give is to use `synchronized` when performing multiple actions that must be seen by other threads as occurring atomically—either all or none of the steps have occurred.

For a single action, `volatile` may be sufficient; it acts as a memory barrier to ensure visibility of the change to other threads.