# volatile vs synchronized for single writer as well as multiple writer threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

First class uses `synchronized` keyword before setter while in second class , I simply mark String field to be `volatile` .

```
public class MyBean{
      private String strValue;

      public synchronized void setStrValue(String strValue){
        this.strValue=strValue;
      }

    public String getStrValue(){
     return strValue
    }

}
```

and

```
public class MyBean{
          private volatile String strValue;

         public void setStrValue(String strValue){
            this.strValue=strValue;
          }

        public String getStrValue(){
         return strValue
        }

    }
```

Are these two pieces of code equivalent as far as reading updated value is concerned from one thread which was updated by another thread?

e.g. if same instance of `MyBean` is passed to two threads - thread - A & thread - B , if target is to have thread - A read updated value after modification is done by thread - B , will both codes be equivalent from that perspective?

Also, in second version ( i.e. when field is marked volatile ) - is it mandatory to place `synchronized` before setter if more than one thread can be a writer? Will `volatile` have any significance for the case of multiple writers for setter method?

Is my assumption correct that both codes are equivalent if there is only one writer thread? 
For the case of multiple writers, will the correct version  be to use `synchronized` as well as `volatile` both ( if don't wish to block readers ) ?

Comment: Can you share example code that uses the bean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use volatile vs synchronization in multithreading in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698285/when-to-use-volatile-vs-synchronization-in-multithreading-in-java)

Comment: @MickMnemonic: am still in design phase and no codes are ready yet so asked the question to clarify my doubts. Writers will be setting different values on different conditions & times , including `EOF` value when a writer would stop reading.

Comment: @Paul- Thanks , I will go through that.

Comment: http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm051.shtml Found this link and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698401/2931410 for your reference

Comment: The version using `synchronized` is not thread safe as the getter also needs to be synchronized. (see Effective Java item 66)