# Does this concurrent legacy code needs volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm struggling with some concurrent legacy code and wonder whether `stopLatch` and/or `mode` should be `volatile`:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private MyModeEnum mode = MyModeEnum.NONE;
    private CountDownLatch stopLatch;

    public synchronized void start(final MyModeEnum mode) {
        assert mode != null && mode != MyModeEnum.NONE;
        if (isRunning()) {
            // Throw an exception.
        }
        this.mode = mode;
        stopLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                // Pre and post operations not under control around stopLatch.await().
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                stop();
                // Further exception handling.
            } finally {
                MyClass.this.mode = MyModeEnum.NONE;
            }
        });
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!isRunning()) {
            return;
        }
        stopLatch.countDown();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return mode != MyModeEnum.NONE;
    }

    public MyModeEnum getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

}
```

Elaborate explanation very appreciated.

**EDIT:** I wasn't able to boil down general questions/answers such as [When exactly do you use the volatile keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3488703/3429133) to this particular problem.

Comment: sync blocks have to synchronize across all threads when they're entered and exited, so I don't think that `volatile` is necessary.

Comment: I would say only `mode` needs to be `volatile`, as any change needs to be visible to other threads. Side note: that `assert` seems to do the same job as `isRunning()`, am I wrong?

Comment: `isRunning()
` is not `synchronized`, so `mode` should be `volatile
`

Comment: @khelwood but, for example, the code within `executor.execute(...)` isn't synchronized anymore. I don't think this is safe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When exactly do you use the volatile keyword in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488703/when-exactly-do-you-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java)

Comment: @sp00m @MickMnemonic I thought of that, too. Are there're any noteworthy pros/cons making `isRunning()` `synchronized` compared with `mode` being `volatile`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214938/java-volatile-modifier-and-synchronized-blocks

Comment: You have data races on `mode`.  It is accessed from outside the sync block.   First choice should be to synchronize `isRunning` and `getMode`; making mode `volatile` is a more advanced play.  (Walk first, then fly.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz, is the code within the anonymous lambda that's passed to `executor.execute()` `synchronized` in the same sense that the rest of the `start()` method is? That's the interesting question here, in my opinion.

Comment: The call to `execute()` _happens-before_ the `Runnable` is executed, whether the execution happens in the local thread or off-thread.  But there's no corresponding _happens-before_ between the completion of the `Runnable` and any action in the initiating thread (or any other thread.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz @sp00m @MickMnemonic thanks for your suggestions regarding the `mode` field. Would anybody mind adding this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Code so young that it uses lambda expressions, but still already “legacy code”…

Comment: @Holger I simplified the original code—written in Java 6— for SO.

Comment: What’s the point of this `stopLatch.await()`? Is the main purpose of the background task to wait to be stopped by someone else?

Comment: @Holger as far as I can tell it acts like a barrier for the post operations to be started.

Comment: So `stop()` means “continue”? But why does the exception handler call `stop()`? It doesn’t do anything useful at the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the most upvoted comments:

- [Mick Mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164162/does-this-concurrent-legacy-code-needs-volatile#comment71493390_42164162):

  > `isRunning()` is not `synchronized`, so `mode` should be `volatile`.
- [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164162/does-this-concurrent-legacy-code-needs-volatile#comment71493994_42164162):

  > You have data races on `mode`. It is accessed from outside the sync block. First choice should be to synchronize `isRunning` and `getMode`; making mode `volatile` is a more advanced play. (Walk first, then fly.)