# Difference between volatile and synchronized in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me, synchronized, volatile

I am wondering at the difference between declaring a variable as `volatile` and always accessing the variable in a `synchronized(this)` block in Java?

According to this article http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml there is a lot to be said and there are many differences but also some similarities.

I am particularly interested in this piece of info:

> ...
>
> - access to a volatile variable never has the potential to block: we're only ever doing a simple read or write, so unlike a synchronized block we will never hold on to any lock;
> - because accessing a volatile variable never holds a lock, it is not suitable for cases where we want to **read-update-write** as an atomic operation (unless we're prepared to "miss an update");

What do they mean by **read-update-write**? Isn't a write also an update or do they simply mean that the **update** is a write that depends on the read?

Most of all, when is it more suitable to declare variables `volatile` rather than access them through a `synchronized` block? Is it a good idea to use `volatile` for variables that depend on input? For instance, there is a variable called `render` that is read through the rendering loop and set by a keypress event?

Answer (score 473, accepted):

It's important to understand that there are *two* aspects to thread safety.

1. execution control, and
2. memory visibility

The first has to do with controlling when code executes (including the order in which instructions are executed) and whether it can execute concurrently, and the second to do with when the effects in memory of what has been done are visible to other threads.  Because each CPU has several levels of cache between it and main memory, threads running on different CPUs or cores can see "memory" differently at any given moment in time because threads are permitted to obtain and work on private copies of main memory.

Using `synchronized` prevents any other thread from obtaining the monitor (or lock) ***for the same object***, thereby preventing all code blocks protected by synchronization ***on the same object*** from executing concurrently.  Synchronization *also* creates a "happens-before" memory barrier, causing a memory visibility constraint such that anything done up to the point some thread releases a lock *appears* to another thread subsequently acquiring ***the same lock*** to have happened before it acquired the lock. In practical terms, on current hardware, this typically causes flushing of the CPU caches when a monitor is acquired and writes to main memory when it is released, both of which are (relatively) expensive.

Using `volatile`, on the other hand, forces all accesses (read or write) to the volatile variable to occur to main memory, effectively keeping the volatile variable out of CPU caches. This can be useful for some actions where it is simply required that visibility of the variable be correct and order of accesses is not important. Using `volatile` also changes treatment of `long` and `double` to require accesses to them to be atomic; on some (older) hardware this might require locks, though not on modern 64 bit hardware. Under the new (JSR-133) memory model for Java 5+, the semantics of volatile have been strengthened to be almost as strong as synchronized with respect to memory visibility and instruction ordering (see http://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile).  For the purposes of visibility, each access to a volatile field acts like half a synchronization.

> Under the new memory model, it is still true that volatile variables cannot be reordered with each other. The difference is that it is now no longer so easy to reorder normal field accesses around them. Writing to a volatile field has the same memory effect as a monitor release, and reading from a volatile field has the same memory effect as a monitor acquire. In effect, because the new memory model places stricter constraints on reordering of volatile field accesses with other field accesses, volatile or not, anything that was visible to thread `A` when it writes to volatile field `f` becomes visible to thread `B` when it reads `f`.
>
> -- [JSR 133 (Java Memory Model) FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html)

So, now both forms of memory barrier (under the current JMM) cause an instruction re-ordering barrier which prevents the compiler or run-time from re-ordering instructions across the barrier. In the old JMM, volatile did not prevent re-ordering. This can be important, because apart from memory barriers the only limitation imposed is that,  *for any particular thread*, the net effect of the code is the same as it would be if the instructions were executed in precisely the order in which they appear in the source.

One use of volatile is for a shared but immutable object is recreated on the fly, with many other threads taking a reference to the object at a particular point in their execution cycle.  One needs the other threads to begin using the recreated object once it is published, but does not need the additional overhead of full synchronization and it's attendant contention and cache flushing.

```
// Declaration
public class SharedLocation {
    static public volatile SomeObject someObject=new SomeObject(); // default object
    }

// Publishing code
SharedLocation.someObject=new SomeObject(...); // new object is published

// Using code
// Note: do not simply use SharedLocation.someObject.xxx(), since although
//       someObject will be internally consistent for xxx(), a subsequent 
//       call to yyy() might be inconsistent with xxx() if the object was 
//       replaced in between calls.
private String getError() {
    SomeObject myCopy=SharedLocation.someObject; // gets current copy
    ...
    int cod=myCopy.getErrorCode();
    String txt=myCopy.getErrorText();
    return (cod+" - "+txt);
    }
// And so on, with myCopy always in a consistent state within and across calls
// Eventually we will return to the code that gets the current SomeObject.
```

Speaking to your read-update-write question, specifically.  Consider the following unsafe code:

```
public void updateCounter() {
    if(counter==1000) { counter=0; }
    else              { counter++; }
    }
```

Now, with the updateCounter() method unsynchronized, two threads may enter it at the same time.  Among the many permutations of what could happen, one is that thread-1 does the test for counter==1000 and finds it true and is then suspended. Then thread-2 does the same test and also sees it true and is suspended. Then thread-1 resumes and sets counter to 0. Then thread-2 resumes and again sets counter to 0 because it missed the update from thread-1.  This can also happen even if thread switching does not occur as I have described, but simply because two different cached copies of counter were present in two different CPU cores and the threads each ran on a separate core. For that matter, one thread could have counter at one value and the other could have counter at some entirely different value just because of caching.

What's important in this example is that the variable *counter* was read from main memory into cache, updated in cache and only written back to main memory at some indeterminate point later when a memory barrier occurred or when the cache memory was needed for something else. Making the counter `volatile` is insufficient for thread-safety of this code, because the test for the maximum and the assignments are discrete operations, including the increment which is a set of non-atomic `read+increment+write` machine instructions, something like:

```
MOV EAX,counter
INC EAX
MOV counter,EAX
```

Volatile variables are useful only when ***all*** operations performed on them are "atomic", such as my example where a reference to a fully formed object is only read or written (and, indeed, typically it's only written from a single point). Another example would be a volatile array reference backing a copy-on-write list, provided the array was only read by first taking a local copy of the reference to it.

Comment: Thanks very much! The example with the counter is simple to understand. However, when things get real, it's a bit different.

Comment: "In practical terms, on current hardware, this typically causes flushing of the CPU caches when a monitor is acquired and writes to main memory when it is released, both of which are expensive (relatively speaking)." . When you say CPU caches, is it the same as Java Stacks local to each thread? or does a thread has its own local version of Heap? Apologize if i am being silly here.

Comment: @nishm It's not the same, but it would include the local caches of the threads involved. .

Comment: Thanks. That clears my ridiculous assumption of cpu caches being equal to thread local java stacks. I should be shot for even thinking that. Nevertheless, it is still not clear what happens when the shared entity is primitive compared to an object ( since sharing a reference would still not affect the visibility aspect of the object data )  . Found an unanswered thread though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552945/thread-caching-and-java-memory-model

Comment: "including the increment which is a non-atomic" doesn't it depend on what type is counter variable? If it's for example int then incrementing is atomic, isn't it?

Comment: @Marian: Nope. Per my pseudo-assembler example. It's a set of read + update + write instructions. Or, more precisely, it might be and is allowed by the JVM spec. I've no idea what current CPU optimizations there may be.

Comment: But you wrote "Making the counter volatile is insufficient for thread-safety of this code" and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html it says "Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).", what do you think?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: An increment or decrement is NOT a read **or** a write, it's a read **and** a write; it's a read into a register, then a register increment, then a write back to memory. Reads and writes are *individually* atomic, but multiple such operations are not.

Comment: In this answer and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664#comment39420456_3519746) you state the following: _"anything that is done **after some thread acquires a lock** appears to another thread"_. To me this seems to be contradictory to what the [Java Memory Model FAQ](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization) states. To me the FAQ seems to say that *every* action on a thread before the unlock of a particular monitor happens-before the lock of the same monitor by another thread (see bullet point list in linked section).

Comment: So, according to the FAQ, *not* only the actions made *since a lock acquisition* are made visible after unlock, but *all* actions made by that thread are made visible. Even actions made before the lock acquisition.

Comment: @LawrenceDol Great answer. Should also introduce [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) in it.

Comment: The paragraph beginning _"One use of volatile is for a shared but immutable object"_ introduces a code example, but `volatile` does not appear anywhere in the example.

Comment: @TiStrga : Oops, yeah. I had originally implied that, thinking it was obvious -- I've now added an explicit declaration.

Answer (score 114):

> **volatile** is a **field modifier**, while **synchronized** modifies **code blocks** and **methods**. So we can specify three variations of a simple accessor using those two keywords:
>
> ```
>     int i1;
>     int geti1() {return i1;}
>
>     volatile int i2;
>     int geti2() {return i2;}
>
>     int i3;
>     synchronized int geti3() {return i3;}
> ```
>
> `geti1()` accesses the value currently stored in `i1` in the current thread.
>   Threads can have local copies of variables, and the data does not have to be the same as the data held in other threads.In particular, another thread may have updated `i1` in it's thread, but the value in the current thread could be different from that updated value. In fact Java has the idea of a "main" memory, and this is the memory that holds the current "correct" value for variables. Threads can have their own copy of data for variables, and the thread copy can be different from the "main" memory. So in fact, it is possible for the "main" memory to have a value of **1** for `i1`, for thread1 to have a value of **2** for `i1` and for **thread2** to have a value of **3** for `i1` if **thread1** and **thread2** have both updated i1 but those updated value has not yet been propagated to "main" memory or other threads.
>
> On the other hand, `geti2()` effectively accesses the value of `i2` from "main" memory. A volatile variable is not allowed to have a local copy of a variable that is different from the value currently held in "main" memory. Effectively, a variable declared volatile must have it's data synchronized across all threads, so that whenever you access or update the variable in any thread, all other threads immediately see the same value. Generally volatile variables have a higher access and update overhead than "plain" variables. Generally threads are allowed to have their own copy of data is for better efficiency.
>
> There are two differences between volitile and synchronized.
>
> Firstly synchronized obtains and releases locks on monitors which can force only one thread at a time to execute a code block. That's the fairly well known aspect to synchronized. But synchronized also synchronizes memory. In fact synchronized synchronizes the whole of thread memory with "main" memory. So executing `geti3()` does the following:
>
> 1. The thread acquires the lock on the monitor for object this .
> 2. The thread memory flushes all its variables, i.e. it has all of its variables effectively read from "main" memory .
> 3. The code block is executed (in this case setting the return value to the current value of i3, which may have just been reset from "main" memory).
> 4. (Any changes to variables would normally now be written out to "main" memory, but for geti3() we have no changes.)
> 5. The thread releases the lock on the monitor for object this.
>
> So where volatile only synchronizes the value of one variable between thread memory and "main" memory, synchronized synchronizes the value of all variables between thread memory and "main" memory, and locks and releases a monitor to boot. Clearly synchronized is likely to have more overhead than volatile.

http://javaexp.blogspot.com/2007/12/difference-between-volatile-and.html

Comment: -1, Volatile does not acquire a lock, it uses the underlying CPU architecture to ensure visibility across all threads after the write.

Comment: It's worth noting that there may be some cases where a lock may be used to guarantee atomicity of writes.  E.g. writing a long on a 32 bit platform that doesn't support extended width rights.  Intel avoids this by using SSE2 registers (128 bits wide) to handle volatile longs.  However, considering a volatile as a lock will likely lead to nasty bugs in your code.

Comment: The important semantic shared by locks a volatile variables is that they both provide Happens-Before edges (Java 1.5 and later).  Entering a synchronized block, taking out a lock and reading from a volatile are all considered as an "acquire" and the release of a lock, exiting a synchronized block and writing a volatile are all forms of a "release".

Answer (score 62):

There are 3 main issues with multithreading:

1. Race Conditions
2. Caching / stale memory
3. Compiler and CPU optimisations

`volatile` can solve 2 & 3, but can't solve 1. `synchronized`/explicit locks can solve 1, 2 & 3.

### **Elaboration**:

1. Consider this thread unsafe code:

`x++;`

While it may look like one operation, it's actually 3: reading the current value of x from memory, adding 1 to it, and saving it back to memory. If few threads try to do it at the same time, the result of the operation is undefined. If `x` originally was 1, after 2 threads operating the code it may be 2 and it may be 3, depending on which thread completed which part of the operation before control was transferred to the other thread. This is a form of **race condition**.

Using `synchronized` on a block of code makes it **atomic** - meaning it make it as if the 3 operations happen at once, and there's no way for another thread to come in the middle and interfere. So if `x` was 1, and 2 threads try to preform `x++` we **know** in the end it will be equal to 3. So it solves the race condition problem.

```
synchronized (this) {
   x++; // no problem now
}
```

Marking `x` as `volatile` does not make `x++;` atomic, so it doesn't solve this problem.

2. In addition, threads have their own context - i.e. they can cache values from main memory. That means that a few threads can have copies of a variable, but they operate on their working copy without sharing the new state of the variable among other threads.

Consider that on one thread, `x = 10;`. And somewhat later, in another thread, `x = 20;`. The change in value of `x` might not appear in the first thread, because the other thread has saved the new value to its working memory, but hasn't copied it to the main memory. Or that it did copy it to the main memory, but the first thread hasn't updated its working copy. So if now the first thread checks `if (x == 20)` the answer will be `false`.

Marking a variable as `volatile` basically tells all threads to do read and write operations on main memory only. `synchronized` tells every thread to go update their value from main memory when they enter the block, and flush the result back to main memory when they exit the block.

Note that unlike data races, stale memory is not so easy to (re)produce, as flushes to main memory occur anyway.

3. The complier and CPU can (without any form of synchronization between threads) treat all code as single threaded. Meaning it can look at some code, that is very meaningful in a multithreading aspect, and treat it as if it’s single threaded, where it’s not so meaningful. So it can look at a code and decide, in sake of optimisation, to reorder it, or even remove parts of it completely, if it doesn’t know that this code is designed to work on multiple threads.

Consider the following code:

```
boolean b = false;
int x = 10;

void threadA() {
    x = 20;
    b = true;
}

void threadB() {
    if (b) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

You would think that threadB could only print 20 (or not print anything at all if threadB if-check is executed before setting `b` to true), as `b` is set to true only after `x` is set to 20, but the compiler/CPU might decide to reorder threadA, in that case threadB could also print 10. Marking `b` as `volatile` ensures that it won’t be reordered (or discarded in certain cases). Which mean threadB could only print 20 (or nothing at all). Marking the methods as syncrhonized will achieve the same result. Also marking a variable as `volatile` only ensures that it won’t get reordered, but everything before/after it can still be reordered, so synchronization can be more suited in some scenarios.

Note that before Java 5 New Memory Model, volatile didn’t solve this issue.

Comment: "While it may look like one operation, it's actually 3: reading the current value of x from memory, adding 1 to it, and saving it back to memory." - Right, because values from memory must go through the CPU circuitry in order to be added/modified. Even though this just turns into a single Assembly `INC` operation, the underlying CPU operations are still 3 fold and requires locking for thread safety. Good point. Although, the `INC/DEC` commands can be atomicly flagged in assembly and still be 1 atomic operation.

Comment: @Zombies so when I create a synchronized block for x++, does it turn it into a flagged atomic INC/DEC or does it use a regular lock?

Comment: I don't know! What I do know is that INC/DEC are not atomic because for a CPU, it has to load the value and READ it and also WRITE it (to memory), just like any other arithmetic operation.

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat - man your #3 example clarified my question. extraordinary explanation. thanks.

Answer (score 27):

[synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

is keyword used to guard a method or code block.  By making method as synchronized , you achieve two things.

> 1. Two executions of `synchronized` methods on the same object never run
> 2. Change in the object state is visible to other threads

`volatile` is variable access modifier which forces all threads to get latest value of the variable from main memory. All threads can access volatile variable value at same time with out any locks.

A good example to use volatile variable : `Date` variable.

Assume that you have made Date variable `volatile`. You don't need different threads showing different time for same variable. All the threads, which access this variable always get latest data from main memory so that all threads show real (actual) Date value.

Lawrence Dol cleary explained your `read-write-update query`.

Regarding your other queries

*When is it more suitable to declare variables volatile than access them through synchronized?*

You have to use `volatile` if you think all threads should get actual value of the variable in real time like Data example covered above.

*Is it a good idea to use volatile for variables that depend on input?*

Answer will be same as in first query.

Comment: So read can happen at same time, and all thread will read latest value because CPU does not cache main memory to CPU thread cache, but what about write? Write must not be concurrent correct? Second question: if a block is synchronized, but variable is not volatile, the value of a variable in a synchronized block can still be changed by another thread in another code block right?