# Thread Caching and Java Memory model

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand the Java memory model and threads. As far as I understand, each thread has a local copy of the "main" memory. So if one thread tries to change an `int` variable, for example, of some object, it caches the `int` variable and if it changes it, other thread might not see the change.

But what if threads cache some object instead of int? What threads cache it in this case? If a thread caches a reference to an object any change to the state of the object are not visible to other threads? Why?

Answer (score 36):

CPU have different level caches L1, L2, L3. Every CPU  (and also /may CPU Core) has own cache. This caches store minimal set of main memory (RAM) for performance.

```
  _______________    ______________  
 |     CPU 1     |  |     CPU 2    |  
 |   _________   |  |   _________  |  
 |  | Level 1 |  |  |  | Level 1 | |  
 |  |   Cache |  |  |  |  Cache  | |  
 |  |         |  |  |  |         | |
 |  |_________|  |  |  |_________| |  
 |_______________|  |______________|
           | |              | |
           | |              | |
          _|_|______________|_|__
         |                       |
         |      MAIN MEMORY      | 
         |_______________________|


  Time     Command                 CPU 1 (Cache)      CPU 2 (Cache)        Main Memory     
-------  ----------              ----------------    --------------       -------------
  1          ---                       ---                ---                x = 10
  2       Read x  (on cpu1)           x = 10              ---                x = 10
  3       Write x <--20 (on cpu1)     x = 20              ---                x = 10       
  4       Read  x (on cpu2)           x = 20              x = 10             x = 10
  5       put cache to Main mem       x = 20              x = 10             x = 20
```

For example, Above execution order, x value is wrong on CPU2. x value already changed by CPU1. 
If x variable is defined as volatile, all write operation reflect to main memory instantly.

Comment: This is incorrect. Caches are always coherent, so it can't happen that after a CPU commits a value to the cache,  a different CPU can still the see old value. Cache coherence algorithms like MESI make sure your above explanation will never happen. And for that reason, a volatile value doesn't need to be written to main memory at all. It could be that it stays in the cache indefinitely. For more information about cache implementations and memory models, please check the following book (free): https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00346ED1V01Y201104CAC016

Answer (score 13):

CPUs have multiple caches.  It is these hardware caches which might have inconsistent copies of the data.  The reason they might be inconsistent is that keeping everything consistent can slow down your code by a factor of 10 and ruin any benefit you get from having multiple threads. To get decent performance you need to be selectively consistent.  The Java Memory Model describes when it will ensure the data is consistent, but in the simplest case it doesn't.

Note: this is not just a CPU issue. A field which doesn't have to consistent between threads can be inlined in the code.  This can mean that if one thread changes the value another thread might NEVER see this change as it has been burnt into the code.

Comment: @Andremoniy the JLS talks about a stack of registers for a virtual machine. It doesn't talk about CPU's actual registers or caches as these are implementation details.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. It is a very important point. May I dare to ask you to look at this question then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263594/auto-optimisation-for-l-cache-for-objects-variables

Comment: I only know a single microprocessor that has incoherent caches, and that is a GPU. Otherwise caches are always coherent.

Answer (score 12):

=============================================================

The answer below is wrong for many reasons. Please do not use for any other purposes than to have a blast. Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent.

=============================================================

A thread doesn't have a local copy of memory. Part of the memory the thread reads/writes could be from a cache, instead of main memory. Caches do not need to be in sync with each other, or in sync with main memory. So this is where you can observe inconsistencies.

> So if one thread tries to change a int variable for example of some object it caches the int variable and if it changes it other thread might not see the change.

That is correct. The Java Memory model is defined in happens before rules, e.g. there is a happens before rule between a volatile write of field x and a volatile read of field x. So when a write is done, a subsequent read will see the value written.

Without such a happens before relation, all bets are off (also instruction reordering can make life complicated when there is no happens before rule).

> If thread caches a reference to an object any change to the state of the object are also not visible to other threads? Why?

It could be visible.. it could also not be visible. Without a happens before rule, all bets are of. The reason why is that otherwise a lot of optimizations like hardware tricks to speed things up, or compiler tricks would not be allowed. And of course, always keeping memory in sync with the cache, would reduce performance.

===========================================================

Comment: Note that "subsequent" is not identical to "occurring after the write". `volatile` doesn't give any *timeliness* guarantees, it is only about *consistency* in never observing writes out of order.

Comment: @pveentjer Why do you say like - it could be visible.. it could also not be visible ? Only the reference cached  in thread local stack. So the changes should be visible across threads. Am I wrong ? Hardware/compiler tricks - Could you please give a clearer picture.

Comment: @Kiran the JMM applies to *any* variable, an object reference is not special in any way. And what makes up an object’s state, is just a bunch of variables.

Answer (score 2):

"Before you can write decent multi-threaded code, however, you really need to study more on the complexities and subtleties of multi-threaded code.

When it comes to threads, very little is guaranteed.

Can you imagine the havoc that can occur when two different threads have access to a single instance of a class, an both threads invoke methods on that object... and those methods modify the state of the object? ... it's too scary to even visualize.", **from Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6, chapter 9: Threads.**

My friend,

In Java, threads doesn't cache any object or variable, they just **have a reference** to an *instance* of an *object*. Talking about *thread cache memory* is more like talking about *operative systems threads*...  Java works in the same way in all OS, no matter how threads are managed internally, which differs very much depending on the  different OS's.

Look a this code:

```
AccountDanger r = new AccountDanger();
Thread one = new Thread(r):
Thread two = new Thread(r);
```

As you can see, in this case threads have access to the same instance: **r**. Then, **you will have synchronization problems**, for sure... it doesn't matters if we talk about **native or object members**, threads one and two will have access to all members of **r** (if they are *accessible* via scope or setters/getters) and they will read directly the values from **r** instance. This is for sure even if you don't notice it, which is sometimes really hard.

I recommend you reading about **java scopes** and **java synchronization**, if you want to code multi-threaded applications.

Regards,