# Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data

Tags: java

I am now reading 《effective Java》 and meeting a confusion.

For code 1 (java8) :

```
public class StopThreadTest {

    private static Boolean stopRequest = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(()->{
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequest) {
                i++;
                //System.out.println("i: " + i);
            }
        }).start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequest = true;
    }
}
```

the program never terminates.

For code 2(java8):

```
public class StopThreadTest {

    private static Boolean stopRequest = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(()->{
            int i = 0;
            while (!stopRequest) {
                i++;
                System.out.println("i: " + i);
            }
        }).start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequest = true;
    }
}
```

Just adding `System.out.println()`, the program run about 1 second.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Is this an official example in effective Java? If so: which edition?

Comment: @Turing85 certainly not in my edition of the book. In fact, the book contradicts this example, saying that both reads and writes of `stopRequest` must be synchronized. Not just some random method whose internal implementation just happens to be synchronized.

Comment: in second edition,  the author use code 1 to address that  both reads and writes of stopRequest must be synchronized.  I just add  add a System.out.println to debug it, just as code 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.out.println()` is synchronized, removing the visibility issues with the original code. Without it, the thread can use its cached value of `stopRequest` and keep on running, but when `println()` is involved, caches are flushed and the modified value can be seen.

From `PrintStream.println(String x)`

```
synchronized (this) {
    print(x);
    newLine();
}
```

Note that this is a side-effect only. It explains the difference in behaviour, but it's not something you can rely on for correct functionality of code.

Comment: For the reason explained from Kayaman, if you define stopRequest as volatile, you avoid the cache problem and the behaviour will be the same for both code: after one second the program will stop.

Comment: I am not quite sure this is correct. While `System.out.println(...)` is `synchronized`, I see no reasoning any reads or writes to `stopRequest` should be `synchronized`. Can you give some JLS refernce to back your statement?

Comment: @KDavid-Valerio This means the code only works because of a side effect of println()`?! I'd be very interested in some links to specs too.

Comment: @blafasel, correct. I think that these question/answers are useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552945/thread-caching-and-java-memory-model

Comment: @Turing85 I'm not sure what you mean. It doesn't guarantee that `stopRequest` would be visible, but in this particular scenario, OS and platform, `stopRequest` gets flushed from cache as a side-effect.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did not know that System.out.println() is synchronized

Comment: @Dustin this can be problematic when an application isn't working due to concurrency/visibility issues, then you add a `System.out.println` to debug it, and suddenly it works just fine.

Comment: @Kayman I am quite sure your answer lacked the last sentenceatn the point in time I wrote my comment :) all is fine now.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you for your advice, I will pay attention to it.