# Why volatile is weaker form of synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

As mentioned from [Java_author](https://www.amazon.ca/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Tim-Peierls-ebook/dp/B004V9OA84/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1/130-5966090-1343009),

> The Java language also provides an alternative, weaker form of synchronization, *volatile variables*, to ensure that updates to a variable are propagated predictably to other threads.

So, my understanding is,

the below code that uses locking(`synchronized`) to provide (mutual exclusion + memory visibility),

```
public class SynchronizedInteger{
    private int value;

    public synchronized int get(){ return value; }
    public synchronized void set(int value){ this.value = value; }
}
```

can also be written just using `volatile` keyword providing (mutual exclusion + memory visibility), shown below,

```
public class SynchronizedInteger{
    private volatile int value;

    public int get(){ return value; }
    public void set(int value){ this.value = value; }
}
```

But,

1. Why `volatile` usage is weaker form of synchronization?
2. Book says: *writing a `volatile` variable is like exiting a `synchronized` block and reading a `volatile` variable is like entering a `synchronized` block*

   Can multiple threads writing to `volatile` memory area `value`, holds mutual exclusion?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `volatile` provides mutual exclusion?

Comment: @shmosel My understanding that `volatile` provides mutual exclusion is because, book says, *writing a `volatile` variable is like exiting a `synchronized` block and reading a `volatile` variable is like entering a `synchronized` block*, which am still not clear, what it means.  I have this in query

Comment: They have the same atomicity and visibility guarantees. There's no concept of mutual exclusion with `volatile`.

Comment: @shmosel But [JSR-133 author](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.ca/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html) says, *Atomicity deals with which actions and sets of actions have indivisible effects. This is the aspect of concurrency most familiar to programmers: it is usually thought of in terms of mutual exclusion.* Aren't atomicity/mutual_exclusion mean same?

Comment: Not in this context. Mutual exclusion is one of several ways to achieve atomicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`volatile` cannot create a critical section on other entities, while `synchronized` can.

e.g.

```
synchronized (something) {
    something.doSomething();
    somethingElse.doSomethingElse();
}
```

With `volatile`, you can "protect" only the entity made volatile.

---

Regarding

> Can multiple threads writing to volatile memory area value, holds mutual exclusion?

No. Each read/write operation on that entity is atomic. Remember that operations like `value++` are composed of read and write, and need to be taken care of separately.

Comment: You mean compound actions can be dealt with `synchronized` unlike `volatile` or `AtomicLong`.

Comment: So, *weaker* in terms of not handling more than what it can? as mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, weaker as in very often you need to use a different mechanism (e.g. `synchronized`) to have your goals met. You cannot do multiple operations with `volatile`, only a simple read or a simple write are atomic.

Comment: Which means that even an increment isn't atomic, since it's a read operation and a write operation.

Answer (score 0):

***volatile*** is variable access modifier which forces all threads to get latest value of the variable from main memory. No locking is required to access volatile variables.

***synchronized*** is method level/block level access restriction modifier. It will make sure that one thread owns the lock for critical section. Only the thread,which own a lock can enter `synchronized` block. If other threads are trying to access this critical section, they have to wait till current owner releases the lock. You can have many statements in `synchronized` blocks/methods.

> Why volatile usage is weaker form of synchronization?

If one thread modifies the value of variable and other threads read the value of that variable, adding `volatile` access modifier to a  variable makes some sense. If multiple threads are modifying and reading value of variable, `volatile` access modifier  does not guarantee data consistency. But if you *synchronize* update/read code blocks, data consistency is guaranteed.

> Can multiple threads writing to volatile memory area value, holds mutual exclusion?

No. Since locking is not involved when you use `volatile` access modifier.

Related post:

[Difference between volatile and synchronized in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java/34355995?s=2|64.1677#34355995)