# volatile varible's memory consistence errors?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

it is said that volatile variables can be used to achieve synchronization. However, volatile variables are still susceptible to memory consistence errors. Why this is so?

Comment: Huh? Can you be more specific? What errors specifically? If you're just asking "what are all the problems that can arise from using only volatile for all synchronization," that's too broad for SO.

Comment: You many want to read about the [difference between volatile and synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Volatile is irrelevant to the synchronization.

Volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable.

[Here is the link to JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

Comment: One needs to be a bit careful with terminology in this area. The happens-before relationship you refer to is due to what the JLS calls "[synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)." The term is overloaded, and I'm not sure which version the OP is referring to (or whether they recognize that it's overloaded).

Answer (score 0):

**No** volatile variables themselves are not subject to memory consistency errors. The volatile variables establish the memory barrier and respect the happens before relationship, so write is flushed to main memory, so that reads are consistent. It's the **operations** that need to be **atomic**.

Assuming  i is int.

`i=10` is ok

`i++` is not atomic, it amounts to reading the current value incrementing it and then pushing it.

For `boolean` variables the only sensible operation is assignment of value , thus they can be used consistently.

Again its the **operations** that need to be **atomic**.

Comment: "For boolean variables the only sensible operation is assignment of value , thus they can be used consistently."  What about `b = !b`? Isn't that analogous to `i++`?

Comment: @yshavit Nice catch yshavit. well use locks then, again it has nothing to do with memory consistency.

Comment: Quite true. It's still not clear to me what the OP was actually asking about, unfortunately. In particular, it's not clear to me whether they're referring to word tearing or something else.