# Java volatile keyword in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, non-volatile

I tried to reproduce the non-volatile variable behavior in Java multi-threading.
Here I have non-volatile variable `test` in *OccurrenceCounter.java* class.
In *ThreadDemo.java* class I have `main` method that spawns two threads.
In `thread1` it continuously check the value of non-volatile variable `test`
in while loop.
If I run below example in *MyRunnableThread1.java* the value of `occurrenceCounter.isTest()` is not taken from CPU cache.

OccurrenceCounter.java:

```
public class OccurrenceCounter {

    // non-volatile variable
    private   boolean test=true;

    public OccurrenceCounter(boolean test)
    {
        this.test=test;
    } 

    public boolean isTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(boolean test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

MyRunnableThread1.java:

```
// Thread 1
public class MyRunnableThread1 implements Runnable {

    private String threadName;
    private OccurrenceCounter occurrenceCounter;

    public MyRunnableThread1(String threadName,OccurrenceCounter occurrenceCounter)
    {
        this.threadName=threadName; 
        this.occurrenceCounter=occurrenceCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread "+threadName + " started");
        System.out.println("value of flag:"+occurrenceCounter.isTest());

        int i=0;
        // random processing code 
        while(i<1000000000L)
        {
           i++; 
           i++;
           i++;
        }
        // checking whether non-volatile variable is taken from cpu cache
        while(occurrenceCounter.isTest())
        {

        }
    System.out.println("Thread "+threadName + " finished");
    }
}
```

MyRunnableThread2.java:

```
// Thread 2
public class MyRunnableThread2 implements Runnable {

    private String threadName;
    private OccurrenceCounter occurrenceCounter;

    public MyRunnableThread2(String threadName,OccurrenceCounter occurrenceCounter)
    {
        this.threadName=threadName; 
        this.occurrenceCounter=occurrenceCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public   void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread "+threadName + " started");

        occurrenceCounter.setTest(false);
        System.out.println("Thread "+threadName + " finished");
    }
}
```

ThreadDemo.java:

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws InterruptedException {

       System.out.println("main thread started");

       OccurrenceCounter occurrenceCounter =new OccurrenceCounter(true);

       MyRunnableThread1 myRunnableThread1=new MyRunnableThread1("Thread1", occurrenceCounter);
       MyRunnableThread2 myRunnableThread2=new MyRunnableThread2("Thread2", occurrenceCounter);

       Thread t1=new Thread(myRunnableThread1);
       Thread t2=new Thread(myRunnableThread2);

       t1.start();

       try
       {
           Thread.sleep(100);
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("main thread sleep exception:"+e);
       }

       t2.start();

       System.out.println("main thread finished");
   }
}
```

Here in *MyRunnableThread1.java* in while loop the the condition `occurrenceCounter.isTest()` is not returned from CPU cache even though `test` variable in `OcuurenceCounter` class is non-volatile.
But if I remove the first while loop:

```
while(i<1000000000L)
{
   i++; 
   i++;
   i++;
}
```

Then I can see that the condition `occurrenceCounter.isTest()` is always false even though it is update by `thread2` and `thread1` never terminates.
So why this while loop:

```
while(i<1000000000L)
{
   i++; 
   i++;
   i++;
}
```

Impacting the behavior of non-volatile variable?
Is this first while loop forcing anyway to read value from memory instead of from CPU cache in of `thread1`? I tried to get answer for this a lot. But I couldn't.

Please anyone help me to figure this out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between volatile and synchronized in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java)

Comment: Without a thread-safe mechanism like `volatile`, `synchronized`, or a java.util.concurrent class, the visibility of data between threads is not well defined.  It may or may not be visible.  Do not rely on what you observe;  rely on what is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

With `volatile`, JMM can gurantee the updated value will be available to other threads.

Without `volatile` or other synchronization, the updated value **could or could not** be available to other threads, it is uncertain.

In this case, the loop

```
while(i<1000000000L) {
    i++; 
    i++;
    i++;
}
```

can not gurantee memory visibility of variable `test`, it is just coincidence. Do not depend on it.

Comment: Hi user6690200, Without this while loop it works fine.But with this while loop it fails every time.I tried this multiple times. Is it due to some how threads are running in same cpu core.Hence all threads are able to read value from same updated cpu cache?Please give ur inputs on this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `volatile` keyword makes sure that if one `Thread` makes some changes on that variable, then other `Thread`s that read it after the change, they will see it. If you use a plain, non-`volatile` variable, then other `Threads` might and might not see it. It depends on the internals of the JVM.

So, how to fix it? There are several ways:

1. As you mentioned, you can make it `volatile`. That's probably the simplest way to do it:

   ```
   public class OccurrenceCounter {

       private volatile  boolean test=true;
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. you can make the accessors `synchornized`. In this case you have to synchronize all the variable accesses:

   ```
   public class OccurrenceCounter {

       private  boolean test=true;

       public OccurrenceCounter(boolean test)
       {
           this.test=test;
       } 

       public synchronized boolean isTest() {
           return test;
       }

       public synchronized void setTest(boolean test) {
           this.test = test;
       }
   }
   ```
3. You  can use an `AtomicBoolean` that handles all of this for you. The price you pay for this is that the API will be slightly more verbose. It's probably an overkill, unless you want to use the `compareAndSet()` or `getAndSet()` methods:

   ```
   private AtomicBoolean test = new AtomicBoolean(true);

   public OccurrenceCounter(boolean test)
   {
       this.test.set(test);
   } 

   public boolean isTest() {
       return test.get();
   }

   public void setTest(boolean test) {
       this.test.set(test);
   }
   ```