# Why is volatile not added to channel of FileInputStream?

Tags: java

`FileChannel channel` doesn't has `volatile`, but `boolean closed` has `volatile`. Below is in Java 8 standard library.

```
public class FileInputStream{
    private FileChannel channel = null;
    private volatile boolean closed = false;
}
```

Comment: Is the chanel _reference_ written and read by different threads and all threads always need to see the most recent value?

Comment: Also, you question is reversed: you state that `channel` has `volatile` (but it does not) and that `closed` is non-volatile (but it is). That's contradictory to the title and the code.

Comment: @knittl i have fixed the description

Comment: @knittl yes, the chanel reference written and read by different threads and all threads always need to see the most recent value.u can see method getChannel and close().

Comment: `getChannel` uses a synchronized block, as [Michael has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65355513/112968). Following the link of the answer explains the effects of volatile and synchronized in the Java Memory Model

Comment: What is the context of this class? is it in the Java standard library, and is it documented?

Comment: @scry this is in the jdk8 standard library

Comment: @knittl I have read "What is the volatile keyword useful for?". I think "FileChannel channel" should be added in this context(jdk8).Is it right?

Comment: @李泽龙 See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3519736/112968, especially the part "In practical terms, on current hardware, this typically causes flushing of the CPU caches when a monitor is acquired and writes to main memory when it is released".

Answer (score 2):

The field is only assigned in a synchronized block, so volatile is not required. Visibility is guaranteed by the monitor lock.

```
public FileChannel getChannel() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (channel == null) {
            channel = FileChannelImpl.open(fd, path, true, false, this);
        }
        return channel;
    }
}
```

See also [What is the volatile keyword useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for)

Comment: public void close() throws IOException {
        synchronized (closeLock) {
            if (closed) {
                return;
            }
            closed = true;
        }

Comment: in this method, The field "closed" is only assigned in a synchronized block, but volatile is added

Comment: @李泽龙 True but [it was not always that way](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/5e55e5e2ee8bf0c262a71ea40c3e88ec4effcdad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/FileInputStream.java#L325). So maybe it got missed, or authors thought it was somehow "safer" to leave it. In any case, it's irrelevant now because they use AtomicBoolean instead of `close` and `closeLock`.

Comment: I have read "What is the volatile keyword useful for?". I think "FileChannel channel" should be added in this context.Is it right?

Comment: @李泽龙 Nope. I cannot word it any more succinctly than in my answer. All of the desirable traits of volatile are achieved by the use of synchronized.