# Example of a memory consistency error when using volatile keyword?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, volatile, consistency

From docs:

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors

But this means that sometimes volatile variables don't work correct?
Strange how it can be used - for my opinion it is very bad code that sometimes work sometimes not. I tried to Google but didn't find example memory consistency error with volatile. Could you please propose one?

Comment: I highly recommend that you read Brian Goetz's "Java concurrency in practice". It's on Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1354080774&sr=8-1&keywords=java+concurrency+in+practice

Comment: It is an excellent book that will demystify just about everything relating to Java's memory and threading models.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is not so much that `volatile` works unreliably. It always works the way it is supposed to work. The problem is that the way it is supposed to work is sometimes not adequate for concurrency control. If you use `volatile` in the wrong situation, you can still get memory consistency errors.

A `volatile` variable will always have any writes propagated to all threads. However, suppose you need to increment the variable among various threads. Doing this<sup>(*)</sup>:

```
volatile int mCounter;

// later, in some code that might be executed simultaneously on multiple threads:
mCounter++;
```

There is a chance that counter increments will be missed. This is because the value of `mCounter` needs to be first read by each thread before a new value can be written. In between those two steps, another thread may have changed the value of `mCounter`. In situations like this, you would need to rely on `synchronized` blocks rather than `volatile` to ensure data integrity.

For more info on `volatile` vs. `synchronized`, I recommend the article [*Managing volatility*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html) by Brian Goetz

<sup>(*)</sup> I realize that the above would be better implemented with `AtomicInteger`; it's a contrived example to illustrate a point.

Answer (score 4):

**Volatile does the following:**

**-** It **prevents the caching the values** in the Thread.

**-** It makes sure that the threads having the copies of the values of the fields of the object reconcile with the main copy present in the memory.

**-** Making sure the **data is written directly to the memory and read from memory itself.**

**## But the condition where volatile fails:**

**-** Making a `Non-Atomic statement Volatile`.

**Eg:**

```
int count = 0;

count++;  // Increment operator is Not Atomic in java
```

**## Better option:**

**1.** Its always better to follow the `Brian's Rule`:

`When ever we write a variable which is next to be read by another thread, or when we are reading a variable which is written just by another thread, it needs to be synchronized.
        The shared fields must be made private, making the read and write methods/atomic statements synchronized.`

**2.** Second option is using the `Atomic Classes`, like **AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, AtomicReference, etc.**

**## See this link, i have asked a similar question like yours:**

[Why Volatile is behaving weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281327/why-volatile-is-behaving-weirdly)